# How to connect circles and lines along a path?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking for a simple way to connect circles and lines along a define path in tikz. I wan't to draw someting like this [image]

Actually im using

`\draw[line width = 1pt, <-] (0,0) .. controls (0,2.5) and (2.5,2.5) .. (5, 5);`

but I don't know, how to connect circles an lines along this path. Does anyone have an idea or knows a usefull library to get this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // I suggest to add two things to your question via the Edit button: 1) Complete code, from preamble, via your drawing statement to `end{document}` , so we can just copy and run to spot your proble. 2) Add a screeshot of what your current drawing statement does produce. // This way it's easier for us to spot problems and suggest solutions for you. Thanks

Comment: See Ti*k*Z  library `decorations.markings`.